# Update Option Type Checkbox to Dropdown

Tags: database, mysql, search

I want to edit my Magento option type for 181 products, changing checkbox and radio to dropdown

Can i just create a mySQL query to change field in catalog_product_option, replacing checkbox and radio with dropdown? Like this example

```
update TABLE_NAME set FIELD_NAME = replace(FIELD_NAME, ‘find this string’, ‘replace found string with this string’);
```

Where

```
FIELD_NAME = TYPE //this is my collumn/field name
TABLE_NAME = catalog_product_option //this is the tablename
find this string = radio //this is the part i want to replace
replace found string with this string = dropdown //this is what I want there instead
```

So

```
update catalog_product_option set type = replace(type, ‘radio’, ‘dropdown’);
```

^ left the template in there for other to look at and adapt

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can achieve this with:

```
UPDATE `catalog_product_option` SET `type` = 'drop_down' WHERE `type` = 'radio';
```

This will update all the options with type radio.
If you want for some specific products use:

```
UPDATE `catalog_product_option` SET `type` = 'drop_down' WHERE `type` = 'radio' AND `product_id` IN (4,5,6,77,89);
```

Before trying it please back-up the table `catalog_product_option`, just in case I'm wrong.